# Ansible 2.0.0.2: ansible doesn't respect the "- u" switch

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm probing a freshly installed Archlinux installation on a Raspberry PI 2 like so:

`ansible -i PI2 arch -m setup -c paramiko -k -u alarm -vvvv`

This reads to me: Fire the setup module against the IP connecting with the user "alarm" asking for the password of this specific user. However the user that eventually attempts to connect is "root".

Here's the debug response:

`Loaded callback minimal of type stdout, v2.0
<192.168.1.18> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: root on PORT 22 TO 192.168.1.18
192.168.1.18 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "ERROR! Authentication failed.", 
    "unreachable": true
}`

The inventory looks like this:

`[arch]
192.168.1.18`

Some things that may or may not be relevant are the following:

- ssh logins via root are not permitted
- sudo is not installed
- default user and pass are "alarm" : "alarm"
- no ssh key being copied to the machine hence the paramiko connection attempt

What is NOT ignored and leads to a successful connection is adding `ansible_user=alarm` to the IP line in the inventory file.

**EDIT** 
Found this interesting passage in the official docs: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable which states:

`Another important thing to consider (for all versions) is that connection specific variables override config, command line and play specific options and directives. For example:`

`ansible_user will override`-u `and`remote_user: `

The original question seems to remain though. Without any mention of `ansible_user` in the inventory, why is root being used instead of the explicitly mentioned user via `- u`?

**EDIT_END**

Is this expected behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: "why is root being used..."  it's most likely because you have `root: yes` in your playbook

Comment: Keep in mind that this is an ad hoc execution via `ansible` only, not `ansible-playbook`. Furthermore in Ansible 2, I think the `ansible_ssh_user` was renamed to `ansible_user`. Cheers

Comment: i'm still used to 1.9 :)  pardon my ignorance on 2.0

Comment: No worries mate. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I virtualenv'd myself a Ansible 1.9.4 sandbox, copied over the ansible.cfg and the inventory and ran the command again. Kinda worked as expected:

`⤷ ansible --version
ansible 1.9.4
  configured module search path = None
(ANS19TEST)~/Documents/Code/VENVS/ANS19TEST
⤷ ansible -i PI2 arch -m setup -c paramiko -k -u alarm -vvvv
SSH password: 
<192.168.1.18> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: alarm on PORT 22 TO 192.168.1.18
<192.168.1.18> REMOTE_MODULE setup`

From where I'm standing I'd say this is a bug. Maybe somebody can confirm?! This goes to the bugtracker then...

Cheers

*EDIT*

For brevity I omitted a important part of my inventory file, which ultimately is responsible for the behavior. It looks like this:

[hypriot]

192.168.1.18 ansible_user=root

[arch]

192.168.1.18

Quote from the Ansible bugtracker:

> The names used in the inventory is the key in a dictionary. So everything you put in there as host-specific variables will be merged into one big dictionary. That means that in some conflicting cases variables are superseded by other values.
>
> You can prevent this by using different names for the same host (e.g. using IP address and hostname, or an alias or DNS-alias) and in that case you can still do what you like to do.

So my inventory looks like this now:

[hypriot]

hypriot_local ansible_host=192.168.1.18 ansible_user=root

[archlinux]

arch_local ansible_host=192.168.1.18

This works fine. The corresponding issue on the Ansible tracker is here: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/14268

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify paramiko as the connection type, Ansible will figure that part out. You may have a `group_vars` directory with an `ansible_user` or `ansible_ssh_user` variable defined for this host which could be overriding the alarm user.

I was able to replicate your test on ansible 2.0.0.2 without any issues against a raspberry pi 2 running Raspian:

```
➜  ansible  ansible -i PI2 arch -m setup -u alarm -vvvv -k
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
SSH password:
Loaded callback minimal of type stdout, v2.0
<192.168.1.84> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: alarm on PORT 22 TO 192.168.1.84
CONNECTION: pid 78534 waiting for lock on 9
CONNECTION: pid 78534 acquired lock on 9

paramiko: The authenticity of host '192.168.1.84' can't be established.
The ssh-rsa key fingerprint is 54e12e8153e0319f450934d606dca7df.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
yes
CONNECTION: pid 78534 released lock on 9
<192.168.1.84> EXEC ( umask 22 && mkdir -p "$( echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1454502995.07-263327298967895 )"     && echo "$( echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1454502995.07-263327298967895 )" )
<192.168.1.84> PUT /var/folders/39/t0dm88q50dbcshd5nc5m5c640000gn/T/tmp5DqywL TO /home/alarm/.ansible/tmp/ansible-    tmp-1454502995.07-263327298967895/setup
<192.168.1.84> EXEC LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /home/alarm/.ansible/    tmp/ansible-tmp-1454502995.07-263327298967895/setup; rm -rf "/home/alarm/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1454502995.    07-263327298967895/" > /dev/null 2>&1
192.168.1.84 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_all_ipv4_addresses": [
            "192.168.1.84"
        ],
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks for testing Dave. Well, in the end it turns out that Ansible 2 respects the `-u` switch. And Ansible 1.9.4 behaves the same way in this regard. It is/was my inventory that messed things up. I omitted a part, which turned out to be important. I'll edit my answer to clarify.